# Shortcode attributes from meta query variables

Tags: shortcode, meta-query

In the following shortcode, I have two variable, `$today` and `$tommorrow` that are being called inside a custom meta query.

```
function display_prognostika_home_loop($atts, $content = null) {
    // Get all the categories
    $taxonomy = 'diorganosi';
    $today = current_time("Y-m-d");
    $tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tomorrow'));

    $parent_terms = get_terms ( 
    array (
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'parent' => 0,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        ) 
    );
    
    
    $terms_list = get_terms($taxonomy,
    array (
        'hide_empty' => true, // change to true if you don't want empty terms
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'exclude' => $parent_terms,
        )
    );  

    ob_start();
    
    // Loop through the $category terms
    foreach ( $terms_list as $term ):
        
    
        $prognostika_loop = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'prognostika',
                'showposts' => -1,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'prog_date_time',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => $taxonomy,
                        'terms'     => array( $term->term_id ),
                        'field'     => 'term_id',
                    )
                ),
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'prog_date_time',
                        'value'     => $today,
                        'compare'   => '=',
                        'type'      => 'DATE',
                    ),
                ),  
            )
        );
        // output category title and posts
        if($prognostika_loop->have_posts()) {
        ?>
        
        <div class="gb-button-wrapper prognostiko-diorganosi-wrapper">

            <span class="gb-button prognostiko-diorganosi"><span class="gb-button-text"><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
                <span class="gb-icon">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" style="enable-background:new 0 0 27.965 27.965" viewBox="0 0 27.965 27.965"><path d="M23.43 12.929c-.021-.021-.043-.034-.064-.052-.025-.029-.047-.061-.07-.09l-6.273-6.269c-.812-.813-2.099-.845-2.871-.071-.773.772-.741 2.061.071 2.872l3.054 3.056H5.967a1.981 1.981 0 1 0 0 3.962h11.254l-3.041 3.037c-.824.826-.867 2.122-.094 2.896.775.772 2.069.731 2.895-.095l6.354-6.354c.826-.824.868-2.12.095-2.892z" style="fill:#030104"></path><path d="M13.983 0C6.262 0 0 6.261 0 13.985c0 7.721 6.262 13.979 13.983 13.979 7.724 0 13.982-6.259 13.982-13.979C27.966 6.261 21.707 0 13.983 0zm0 26.535c-6.933 0-12.551-5.619-12.551-12.549 0-6.934 5.619-12.551 12.551-12.551s12.551 5.617 12.551 12.551c0 6.93-5.619 12.549-12.551 12.549z" style="fill:#030104"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </span>

        </div>
                
        <?php
        //$cat_object = $prognostika_loop->get_queried_object();
        //$cats = $cat_object->count;
        //var_dump ($cat_object);
    
        while ($prognostika_loop->have_posts()) : $prognostika_loop->the_post();
        do_action('prognostika_loop');
        endwhile;
        }
    
        // Reset query
        $customQuery = null;
        wp_reset_postdata();

    // end the loop
    endforeach;
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('prognostika_home_loop', 'display_prognostika_home_loop');
```

I would like to set up attributes so that

`[prognostika_home_loop today]` - Display today's posts
`[prognostika_home_loop tomorrow]` - Display tomorrow's posts

meaning `today` and `tomorrow` would affect the `'value'=> $today` pair. When today is used, pair would become `'value' => $today`. When tomorrow is used, pair would become `'value' => $tomorrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the attribute value to decide today and tomorrow like:**

**Code explanation:** Instead of **today** and **tomorrow** naming in shortcode, I'm using **show_for** in this answer. Based on **show_for** value we can update the meta query later on. In the code, I checked if **show_for** is set by user or it exists in the `$atts` array. If yes, I set the `$prog_time` variable based on the `$atts['show_for']` value. If no, I set the **default** value for `$prog_time`.

```
if(isset($atts['show_for'])) { 
 switch($atts['show_for']) {
   case 'today' : $prog_time = current_time("Y-m-d"); break; 
   case 'tomorrow' : $prog_time = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tomorrow')); break;
   default : $prog_time = current_time("Y-m-d"); break; 
 }
} else { 
  $prog_time = current_time("Y-m-d"); 
}
```

Now, there is no need to use `$today` and `$tomorrow` separately. Use only `$prog_time` instead of `$today` in the **meta query**.

```
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'prog_date_time',
                'value'     => $prog_time, // updated here; will have dynamic time as decided in switch clause
                'compare'   => '=',
                'type'      => 'DATE',
            ),
        ),
```

---

Your shortcode call will be like:

- `[prognostika_home_loop show_for="today"]`
- `[prognostika_home_loop show_for="tomorrow"]`
- and you can configure many in switch clause for **passed, yesterday**, etc.

---

Additional Notes:

- Since you're using `Y-m-d` format, make sure `prog_date_time` (while saving post meta) value is also set/updated with the same format for matching.
- If you've multiple attributes, setting default values for attributes is recommended.

Comment: Apart form a parenthesis and a `break;` missing, the code works great!


`if( isset($atts['show_for']) ) { 
 switch($atts['show_for']) {
   case 'today' : $prog_time = current_time("Y-m-d"); break; 
   case 'tomorrow' : $prog_time = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tomorrow')); break; 
   default : $prog_time = current_time("Y-m-d"); break; 
 }
} else { 
  $prog_time = current_time("Y-m-d"); 
}`

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer. :)